# Working with angular and node at same time

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am working on simple Angular app. Everything is working from angular side.

I created `server.js` file and included express inside of it. I am not able to run `node server.js` in the command line.

What is the way to work with both angular and node.

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: Post your server.js code also

Comment: Can you please share the error which you are getting. You should run these commands inside the nodejs project `npm i -g express` and `node server.js` .

Answer (score 0):

Angular app and express js servr app should both be in different folder and check if express js is installed

If not installed use this command

```
npm i -g express
```

Then try the above command

```
node server.js
```